# HaProxy as HttpProxy with list of underlying proxies

Tags: proxy, haproxy, http-proxy

Is it possible to configure haproxy as a real http proxy which can forward requests to other proxies?
What I want to do: I have a list of working proxies. I want to configure haproxy to proxy via these proxies.

I thought about such case:

```
frontend proxy
 bind *:80
 default_backend proxyBackend
 option http_proxy
backend proxyBackend
 option http_proxy
 server server1 35.199.76.79:80 
 server server2 198.1.122.29:80 
 balance roundrobin
```

Example:
curl --proxy localhost:80 http://check-host.net/ip
I thought that request will go throw proxy server1 or server2. But it fails.

Is it possible? Or who can recommend good solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution:

```
global
 daemon
 maxconn 256
defaults
 mode http
 timeout connect 5000ms
 timeout client 50000ms
 timeout server 50000ms
listen stats
 bind *:9999
 stats enable
 stats hide-version
 stats uri /stats
frontend proxy
 bind *:80
 default_backend proxyBackend
 option http_proxy
 option http-use-proxy-header
backend proxyBackend
 server serverName1 35.199.76.79:80
 server serverName2 198.1.122.29:80
 server serverName3 129.213.76.9:3128
 balance roundrobin
```

For such configuration we have proxy list rotation using haproxy. So great.

Comment: Could you kindly explain the role of option http_proxy and option http-use-proxy-header? Why we need both?

Comment: you can omit these 2 parameters, it's my custom case.
http_proxy doesn't do DNS lookups, only explicit IPs

Comment: http-use-proxy-header (https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4.2-option%20http-use-proxy-header) By setting this option in a frontend, haproxy can automatically switch to use
that non-standard header if it sees proxied requests

Comment: http-use-proxy-header must absolutely be avoided. It's very likely that we'll drop it in 1.9 and emit a warning to report the requirement to the client and proxy vendors. No browser uses it anymore, and no proxy should be using it anymore either. Support for this was added in haproxy in 2010, or 4 years before the HTTP RFCs were rewritten to clarify corner cases.